# Format numbers to roman numerals?

Tags: vb.net, number-formatting

Is it possible to use Format function to display integers in roman numerals?

```
For Counter As Integer = 1 To 10
   Literal1.Text &= Format(Counter, "???")
Next
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no standard formatter for that.

If you read the [Wikipedia on Roman numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals) you'll find that there are multiple ways of formatting Roman Numerals. So you will have to write your own method our [use the code of someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7040289/converting-integers-to-roman-numerals).

Comment: Are you sure sir? Coz I'm gonna grab that converter class if Format can't give me what I need.

Comment: I have never seen one in the framework: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx That is how sure I am.

Comment: Considering the number of developers creating class for that. I think there is no hope I can find in Format function. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

This is what I found on http://www.source-code.biz/snippets/vbasic/7.htm

(originally written by Mr **Christian d'Heureuse** in VB)

I converted it to VB.net:

```
   Private Function FormatRoman(ByVal n As Integer) As String
      If n = 0 Then FormatRoman = "0" : Exit Function
      ' there is no Roman symbol for 0, but we don't want to return an empty string
      Const r = "IVXLCDM" ' Roman symbols
      Dim i As Integer = Math.Abs(n)
      Dim s As String = ""

      For p As Integer = 1 To 5 Step 2
         Dim d As Integer = i Mod 10
         i = i \ 10
         Select Case d ' format a decimal digit
            Case 0 To 3 : s = s.PadLeft(d + Len(s), Mid(r, p, 1))
            Case 4 : s = Mid(r, p, 2) & s
            Case 5 To 8 : s = Mid(r, p + 1, 1) & s.PadLeft(d - 5 + Len(s), Mid(r, p, 1))
            Case 9 : s = Mid(r, p, 1) & Mid(r, p + 2, 1) & s
         End Select
      Next

      s = s.PadLeft(i + Len(s), "M") ' format thousands
      If n < 0 Then s = "-" & s ' insert sign if negative (non-standard)
      FormatRoman = s
   End Function
```

I hope this will help others.

Cheers - Dave.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this code that works perfectly up to a million.
You can use it but, please, do not make it your own.

```
Public NotInheritable Class BRoman
'Written by Bernardo Ravazzoni
Public Shared Function hexRoman(ByVal input As Integer) As String
    Return mainROMAN(input)
End Function
Private Shared Function mainROMAN(ByVal input As Integer) As String
    Dim under As Boolean = udctr(input)
    Dim cifretotali As Integer = input.ToString.Length
    Dim output As String = ""
    Dim remaning As String = input
    Dim cifracor As Integer = cifretotali
    While Not cifracor = 0
        output = output & coreROMAN(division(remaning, remaning), cifracor)
        cifracor = cifracor - 1
    End While
    If under Then
        output = "-" & output
    End If
    Return output
End Function
Private Shared Function coreROMAN(ByVal num As Integer, ByVal pos As Integer) As String
    Dim output As String = ""
    Debug.WriteLine(num)
    Select Case num
        Case 1 To 3
            output = say(num, getStringFor(True, pos))
        Case 4
            output = getStringFor(True, pos) & getStringFor(False, pos)
        Case 5 To 8
            output = getStringFor(False, pos) & say(num - 5, getStringFor(True, pos))
        Case 9, 10
            output = say(10 - num, getStringFor(True, pos)) & getStringFor(True, pos + 1)
    End Select
    Return output
End Function
Private Shared Function getStringFor(ByVal first As Boolean, ByVal index As Integer) As String
    Dim output As String = ""
    index = index * 2
    If first Then
        index = index - 1
    End If
    output = rGetStringFor(index)
    Return output
End Function
Private Shared Function rGetStringFor(ByVal index As Integer) As String
    Dim output As String = ""
    Dim sy As Integer
    If index < 8 Then
        output = rrGetStringFor(index)
    Else
        sy = index \ 6
        output = say(sy, rrGetStringFor(8)) & rrGetStringFor(((index - 2) Mod 6) + 2) & say(sy, rrGetStringFor(9))
    End If
    Return output
End Function
Private Shared Function rrGetStringFor(ByVal index As Integer) As String
    Dim output As String = ""
    Select Case index
        Case 1
            output = "I"
        Case 2 '8
            output = "V"
        Case 3 '9
            output = "X"
        Case 4 '10
            output = "L"
        Case 5 '11
            output = "C"
        Case 6 '12
            output = "D"
        Case 7 '13
            output = "M"
        Case 8
            output = "["
        Case 9
            output = "]"
    End Select
    Return output
End Function
Private Shared Function division(ByVal inputs As String, ByRef resto As String) As Integer
    resto = ""
    If inputs.Length > 1 Then
        resto = inputs.Substring(1)
    End If
    Dim output As Integer = Integer.Parse(StrReverse(inputs).Substring(inputs.Length - 1))
    Return output
End Function
Public Shared Function say(ByVal index As Integer, ByVal letter As String) As String
    Dim output As String = ""
    While Not index = 0
        output = output & letter
        index = index - 1
    End While
    Return output
End Function
Public Shared Function udctr(ByRef num As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim und As Boolean = (num < 0)
    If und Then
        num = 0 - num
    End If
    Return und
End Function
End Class
```

Use the function hexRoman, like this example:

```
msgbox(Broman.hexRoman(50))
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is ancient, but, in case anyone finds this useful, I wanted to add the function `nRoman()`, below, that I wrote a while back based on the source function @Dave mentioned—instead of constructing output from basic Latin ASCII characters (i.e., {I, V, X, L, C, D, M} or {i, v, x, l, c, d, m}), it uses Roman numerals, found in the the range, `U+2160` to `U+2188`, of the 'Number Forms' group (i.e., {Ⅰ, Ⅴ, Ⅹ, Ⅼ, Ⅽ, Ⅾ, Ⅿ, ↁ, ↂ, ↇ, ↈ} or {ⅰ, ⅴ, ⅹ, ⅼ, ⅽ, ⅾ, ⅿ, ↁ, ↂ, ↇ, ↈ}).

I referenced existing functions, so I included those as well.  I wrote this in VBA (Excel), so some adjustments will be needed in a different environment (e.g., unicode Roman numeral characters are referenced with function calls to make them easier to remember, but 'WorksheetFunction.Unichar()' would need to be replaced with the appropriate function to interpret Unicode code points).

*Adjustments*:

- My function uses *5000 = ↁ*, *10000 = ↂ*, *50000 = ↇ*, and *100000 =
  ↈ* (I also included an analogous version the original function,
  `numRoman()`, that uses ASCII Latin characters up to *1000 = M*, but
  uses different bracket characters as placeholders for these four
  values)—if you'd rather output not not utilize these, I think you can
  just adjust the line that modifies the hundred-thousands place to
  modify the thousands place instead.
- Instead of using a string / `mid()` to store and identify numerals,
  like in the original function, I used an array / index—this is
  because `len()` and `mid()` don't behave consistently in different
  languages / environments for unicode code points above 55296,
  sometimes interpreting characters with those code points as a
  sequence of two characters (I don't recall exactly what is going on,
  but I think the first character's code point is read as 55357,
  although this may vary for some subrange) instead of a single
  character, which use of an array avoids.

**────────────────────────────────────────────────**

**Module**: `mNumeralSystem`

```
Option Explicit

Public Function nRoman(ByVal n As Long, Optional ByVal lowCase As Boolean = False) As String                                                                                                    ' _
• Converts arabic to Roman numeral, using special unicode characters (instead of regular ASCI letters used to construct the output of 'numRoman()')                                             ' _
    § DECLARE
        Dim _
            i           As Long, _
            s           As String, _
            p           As Long, _
            d           As Long, _
            r           As Variant
                                                                                                                                                                                                ' _
    § DEFINE
        If n = 0 Then nRoman = "0": Exit Function                                               '   » There is no roman symbol for 0, but we don't want to return an empty string.
        If lowCase Then                                                                         '   » roman numerals, unicode special, lowercase (as array)
            r = Array( _
                        cRomanL1, cRomanL5, cRomanL10, cRomanL50, cRomanL100, cRomanL500, _
                        cRomanL1000, cRoman5000, cRoman10000, cRoman50000, cRoman100000 _
                      )
        Else                                                                                    '   » roman numerals, unicode special, uppercase (as array)
            r = Array( _
                        cRoman1, cRoman5, cRoman10, cRoman50, cRoman100, cRoman500, _
                        cRoman1000, cRoman5000, cRoman10000, cRoman50000, cRoman100000 _
                      )
        End If
        
        ReDim Preserve r(1 To arrayCount(r))                                                    '   » converting base to 1 simplifies coding
        i = Abs(n)
        For p = 1 To 9 Step 2
            d = i Mod 10: i = i \ 10
            Select Case d                                                                       '   » format a decimal digit
                Case 0 To 3: s = String(d, r(p)) & s
                Case 4:      s = r(p) & r(p + 1) & s
                Case 5 To 8: s = r(p + 1) & String(d - 5, r(p)) & s
                Case 9:      s = r(p) & r(p + 2) & s
             End Select
        Next
        s = String(i, cRoman100000) & s                                                         '   » format hundred-thousands
        If n < 0 Then s = "-" & s                                                               '   » insert sign if negative (non-standard)
                                                                                                                                                                                                ' _
    § RETURN
        nRoman = s
        
End Function
Public Function numRoman(ByVal n As Long) As String                                                                                                                                             ' _
• Converts arabic to Roman numeral (ASCI letters)                                                                                                                                               ' _
 † Note, modified original function (commented above), adding to the co-domain, brackets as placeholders for Roman numerals lacking ASCI analogs, _
   to permit surjective mapping from the ASCI co-domain to the special unicode versions in the co-domain for 'nRoman()'.                                                                        ' _
    § DECLARE
        Const r = "IVXLCDM)(]["                                                                 '   » roman numerals, ASCI characters (as string, brackets stand in where no ASCI equivalent exists (i.e., 5000, 10000, 50000, 100000)
        Dim _
            i       As Long, _
            s       As String, _
            p       As Long, _
            d       As Long
                                                                                                                                                                                                ' _
    § DEFINE
        i = Abs(n)
        If n = 0 Then numRoman = "0": Exit Function                                             '   » There is no roman symbol for 0, but we don't want to return an empty string.
        For p = 1 To 9 Step 2
           d = i Mod 10: i = i \ 10
           Select Case d                                                                        '   » format a decimal digit
              Case 0 To 3: s = String(d, Mid(r, p, 1)) & s
              Case 4:      s = Mid(r, p, 2) & s
              Case 5 To 8: s = Mid(r, p + 1, 1) & String(d - 5, Mid(r, p, 1)) & s
              Case 9:      s = Mid(r, p, 1) & Mid(r, p + 2, 1) & s
            End Select
         Next
        s = String(i, "[") & s                                                                  '   » format hundred-thousands
        If n < 0 Then s = "-" & s                                                               '   » insert sign if negative (non-standard)
                                                                                                                                                                                                ' _
    § RETURN
        numRoman = s
   
End Function
```

**────────────────────────────────────────────────**

**Module**: `mCharacterNames`

```
Option Explicit

'Characters _
Function Name                                       Function Return                                                     End Function    singleQuote Character
Function cRoman1() As String:                       cRoman1 = WorksheetFunction.Unichar(8544):                          End Function    '           ?
Function cRoman10() As String:                      cRoman10 = WorksheetFunction.Unichar(8553):                         End Function    '           ?
Function cRoman100() As String:                     cRoman100 = WorksheetFunction.Unichar(8557):                        End Function    '           ?
Function cRoman1000() As String:                    cRoman1000 = WorksheetFunction.Unichar(8559):                       End Function    '           ?
Function cRoman10000() As String:                   cRoman10000 = WorksheetFunction.Unichar(8578):                      End Function    '           ?
Function cRoman100000() As String:                  cRoman100000 = WorksheetFunction.Unichar(8584):                     End Function    '           ?
Function cRoman5() As String:                       cRoman5 = WorksheetFunction.Unichar(8548):                          End Function    '           ?
Function cRoman50() As String:                      cRoman50 = WorksheetFunction.Unichar(8556):                         End Function    '           ?
Function cRoman500() As String:                     cRoman500 = WorksheetFunction.Unichar(8558):                        End Function    '           ?
Function cRoman5000() As String:                    cRoman5000 = WorksheetFunction.Unichar(8577):                       End Function    '           ?
Function cRoman50000() As String:                   cRoman50000 = WorksheetFunction.Unichar(8583):                      End Function    '           ?
Function cRomanL1() As String:                      cRomanL1 = WorksheetFunction.Unichar(8560):                         End Function    '           ?
Function cRomanL10() As String:                     cRomanL10 = WorksheetFunction.Unichar(8569):                        End Function    '           ?
Function cRomanL100() As String:                    cRomanL100 = WorksheetFunction.Unichar(8573):                       End Function    '           ?
Function cRomanL1000() As String:                   cRomanL1000 = WorksheetFunction.Unichar(8575):                      End Function    '           ?
Function cRomanL5() As String:                      cRomanL5 = WorksheetFunction.Unichar(8564):                         End Function    '           ?
Function cRomanL50() As String:                     cRomanL50 = WorksheetFunction.Unichar(8572):                        End Function    '           ?
Function cRomanL500() As String:                    cRomanL500 = WorksheetFunction.Unichar(8574):                       End Function    '           ?
```

**────────────────────────────────────────────────**

**Module**: `mArrayTools`

```
Option Explicit

Public Function NumberOfArrayDimensions(ByVal arr As Variant) As Integer                                                                                                                        ' _
• Returns the number of dimensions of array (up to 60000), 'arr', by exploiting error hanlding                                                                                                  ' _
    § DECLARE
        Dim _
            n               As Long, _
            errIncrement    As Long, _
            a               As Variant
                                                                                                                                                                                                ' _
    § DEFINE
        a = arr
        On Error GoTo FinalDimension
        For n = 1 To 60000                                  '   » loop through VBA max of 60000 array dimensions
           errIncrement = LBound(a, n)
        Next n
    Exit Function
FinalDimension:                                                                                                                                                                                 ' _
    § RETURN
        NumberOfArrayDimensions = n - 1                     '   » return last 'n' before 'n' that returned error
        
End Function
Function arrayCount(a As Variant, Optional ByVal uniq As Boolean = False) As Long                                                                                                               ' _
• Returns number of elements in array, 'a' (or, if 'uniq' = True, the number of unique values), by:                                                                                             ' _
  › for 'a' dimensions = 1, using upper/lower bounds, or                                                                                                                                        ' _
  › for 'a' dimensions > 1, counting via for-each loop                                                                                                                                          ' _
    § DECLARE
        Dim _
            n       As Long, _
            x       As Variant, _
            d       As Scripting.Dictionary, _
            b       As Boolean
                                                                                                                                                                                                ' _
    § DEFINE
        Select Case uniq
            Case False
                If NumberOfArrayDimensions(a) = 1 Then
                        n = UBound(a) - LBound(a) + 1
                Else:   For Each x In a:    n = n + 1:  Next
                End If
            Case Else
                Set d = New Scripting.Dictionary
                For Each x In a:    d(x) = b:   Next
                n = d.Count
        End Select
                                                                                                                                                                                                ' _
    § RETURN
        arrayCount = n
        
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Public Class RomanNumber
    Public Shared Function FromNumber(val As Byte) As String
        Return GetNumberToRoman(val)
    End Function
    Public Shared Function FromNumber(val As SByte) As String
        Return GetNumberToRoman(val)
    End Function
    Public Shared Function FromNumber(val As Int16) As String
        Return GetNumberToRoman(val)
    End Function
    Public Shared Function FromNumber(val As Int32) As String
        Return GetNumberToRoman(val)
    End Function
    Public Shared Function FromNumber(val As UInt16) As String
        Return GetNumberToRoman(val)
    End Function
    Public Shared Function FromNumber(val As UInt32) As String
        Return GetNumberToRoman(val)
    End Function
    Public Shared Function ToByte(val As String) As Byte
        Return GetNumberFromRoman(val)
    End Function
    Public Shared Function ToSByte(val As String) As SByte
        Return GetNumberFromRoman(val)
    End Function
    Public Shared Function ToInt16(val As String) As Int16
        Return GetNumberFromRoman(val)
    End Function
    Public Shared Function ToInt32(val As String) As Int32
        Return GetNumberFromRoman(val)
    End Function
    Public Shared Function ToUInt16(val As String) As UInt16
        Return GetNumberFromRoman(val)
    End Function
    Public Shared Function ToUInt32(val As String) As UInt32
        Return GetNumberFromRoman(val)
    End Function
    Private Shared Function GetNumberToRoman(val As Integer) As String
        Dim v As String = ""
        Do While val > 0
            If val >= 1000 Then
                v &= "M" : val -= 1000
            ElseIf val >= 900 Then
                v &= "CM" : val -= 900
            ElseIf val >= 500 Then
                v &= "D" : val -= 500
            ElseIf val >= 400 Then
                v &= "CD" : val -= 400
            ElseIf val >= 100 Then
                v &= "C" : val -= 100
            ElseIf val >= 90 Then
                v &= "XC" : val -= 90
            ElseIf val >= 50 Then
                v &= "L" : val -= 50
            ElseIf val >= 40 Then
                v &= "XL" : val -= 40
            ElseIf val >= 10 Then
                v &= "X" : val -= 10
            ElseIf val >= 9 Then
                v &= "IX" : val -= 9
            ElseIf val >= 5 Then
                v &= "V" : val -= 5
            ElseIf val >= 4 Then
                v &= "IV" : val -= 4
            Else
                v &= "I" : val -= 1
            End If
        Loop
        Return v
    End Function
    Private Shared Function GetNumberFromRoman(val As String) As Object
        Dim v As Integer = 0
        If val.Contains("IV") Then v += 4 : val = val.Replace("IV", "")
        If val.Contains("IX") Then v += 9 : val = val.Replace("IX", "")
        If val.Contains("XL") Then v += 40 : val = val.Replace("XL", "")
        If val.Contains("XC") Then v += 90 : val = val.Replace("XC", "")
        If val.Contains("CD") Then v += 400 : val = val.Replace("CD", "")
        If val.Contains("CM") Then v += 900 : val = val.Replace("CM", "")
        For Each c As Char In val
            If c = "I" Then v += 1
            If c = "V" Then v += 5
            If c = "X" Then v += 10
            If c = "L" Then v += 50
            If c = "C" Then v += 100
            If c = "D" Then v += 500
            If c = "M" Then v += 1000
        Next
        Return v
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to also provide some explanations to explain your reasoning and what it does.