# Converting arabic numerals to roman numerals in a visual basic console application

Tags: vb.net, numbers, console-application, roman-numerals

I want to convert positive integers to roman integers in a VB console application. I'm a newbie and I like know a simpler way to convert normal numbers to roman. And can you explain how to create a function to this more effectively and easily

Comment: Don't think there's a function, you'll have to create one. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305822/format-numbers-to-roman-numerals)

Comment: do you know a simpler way to create a function